# Is there split screen multiplayer in minecraft xbox one?

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

Also, what are the requirements for 2-player split screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have a HDTV and a HDMI cable for your xbox.

1. Start Minecraft when you've logged on with your first controller.
2. Enter your desired world. Pause the game.
3. Turn on and sync your other controllers if they haven't been
   connected before. (optional)
4. Log in those controllers and press Resume Game.

Your television screen should be split into two or four parts depending on how many controllers are connected.

5. Enjoy the game.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to have split-screen on the Xbox One!

[image]

Comment: You should add some kind of tutorial